# Problem with using map to populate select in React / Material UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to populate Material's UI  with a list of countries, like so:

```
import React from "react";
import FormControl from "@material-ui/core/FormControl";
import InputLabel from "@material-ui/core/InputLabel";
import Select from "@material-ui/core/Select";
import MenuItem from "@material-ui/core/MenuItem";
import countries from "./data";

const simpleCountrySelect = props => {
  return (
    <>
      <FormControl>
        <InputLabel id="countrySelectLabel">Country</InputLabel>
        <Select labelId="countrySelectLabel" id="countrySelect" value=''>
          {countries.map((code, name, index) => (
            <MenuItem key={index} value={code}>
              {name}
            </MenuItem>
          ))}
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
    </>
  );
};

export default simpleCountrySelect;
```

Uncontrolled component for the brevity sake. But I'm getting the following error:

```
Encountered two children with the same key, `.$.$.$[object Object]`. Keys should be unique so that components maintain their identity across updates. Non-unique keys may cause children to be duplicated and/or omitted — the behavior is unsupported and could change in a future version.
```

Here is sample of the `data.js` file:

```
export default [
  { code: "AD", name: "Andorra" },
  { code: "AE", name: "United Arab Emirates" },
  { code: "AF", name: "Afghanistan" },
  { code: "AG", name: "Antigua and Barbuda" }
];
```

What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT: changed `key` from `code` to `index`, still nothing.

Comment: Are you sure that code is unique ?
From the error it looks like, you are passing an object instead of string.

Comment: Good point! I'm not sure about the uniqueness of the country code. I changed it to `index`, see my updated question.

Comment: Although using index may work, but it is not recommended.
More on that here : https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you meant to destructure each object in the array but you've missed the curly braces:

```
countries.map(({code, name}) =>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is acturally `map` method used mistake.

The parameters transfer to the function in `map` are present `item`, `index`, `array` in order. In your case, `countries.map((code, name, index) => {...})`, `code` present single item in data array, such as `{code: "AD", name: "Andorra"}`, `name` present index of data array, `index` present data array itself. You got the same key error is because they are the same value - the data array.

So, the right way to write map function in your purpose should be as below:

```js
countries.map(({ code, name }, index) => (
  <MenuItem key={index} value={code}>
    {name}
  </MenuItem>
))
```

The whole file should be as below:

```js
import React from "react";
import FormControl from "@material-ui/core/FormControl";
import InputLabel from "@material-ui/core/InputLabel";
import Select from "@material-ui/core/Select";
import MenuItem from "@material-ui/core/MenuItem";
import countries from "./data";

const simpleCountrySelect = props => {
  return (
    <>
      <FormControl>
        <InputLabel id="countrySelectLabel">Country</InputLabel>
        <Select labelId="countrySelectLabel" id="countrySelect" value=''>
          {countries.map(({code, name}, index) => (
            <MenuItem key={index} value={code}>
              {name}
            </MenuItem>
          ))}
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
    </>
  );
};

export default simpleCountrySelect;
```

Answer (score 0):

Encountered two children with the same key is a warning which says two of your menu item has the same key, since your using country code as the key, it might as well be true. I would suggest something like an index of your array to be used as a key.
Secondly you got to return in a map.
So it should be something like

```
countries.map((index, code, name) => {
return(
<Menu.Item key={index} value={code}>
   {name}
</Menu.Item>
)})
```

Try this, it should be good to go.

Comment: Return isn't necessary with arrow functions if you forgo the curly braces around it, and it's not recommended to use an index as a key (although I can't recall why that is)